# The difference between timestamps in minutes

Tags: c++, time, compare

How do I compare two timestamps with format `yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss` to get the total difference in minutes?

The timestamps are retrieved from MySQL. So far I've tried using time_t or even breaking down the whole string to compare but the problem with the latter is it doesnt recognize the difference in days.

thanks in advance!

edit1:
by comparing the timestamps i need to check whether the difference is bigger than x minutes.

like:

```
timestamp1 = getTimestampFunction1();
timestamp2 = getTimestampFunction2();

difference = timestamp1 - timestamp2; //difference in minutes

if (difference > 60)
{
    do this;
}
else
{
    do that;
}
```

Comment: You start by writing some C++.

Comment: Now what do you want? Difference in minutes? Difference in days? Or just compare?

Comment: yea sorry, havent slept for 2 days and reading numerous articles didnt help either :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with boost

```
#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp>

#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::local_time;
using namespace boost::posix_time;

class DateTimeDiff {
    istringstream ss;
    local_time_input_facet* facet;
public:
    DateTimeDiff(char const * format)
    : facet(new local_time_input_facet(format)) {
        ss.imbue(locale(ss.getloc(), facet));
    }
    double delta_minutes( string t0, string t1 ) {
        local_date_time ldt0(not_a_date_time), ldt1(not_a_date_time);
        ss.str(t0); ss >> ldt0;
        ss.str(t1); ss >> ldt1;
        return time_duration(ldt1 - ldt0).total_seconds() / 60.0;
    }
};

int main() {
    DateTimeDiff dt("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S");

    const string t0 = "2013-01-02 13-14-27",
                 t1 = "2013-02-01 12-56-09";

    double diff = dt.delta_minutes(t0,t1);

    cout << t0 << " and "
         << t1 << " are "
         << diff << " minutes apart."
         << endl;

    cout << diff << " minutes is ";
    if (diff > 60) {
        cout << "more than";
    } else {
        cout << "less than or equal to";
    }
    cout << " one hour." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
2013-Jan-02 13:14:27 UTC and 2013-Feb-01 12:56:09 UTC are 43181.7 minutes apart.
43181.7 minutes is more than one hour.
```

Comment: awesome! didnt try boost before (as i didnt want to use other libraries) now its working like a charm. thanks! I do have many "implicit conversion losing integer precision" from using boost though. any way i could fix this?

Comment: Perhaps you are using Apple LLVM/Xcode? I found this reference
https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6635
I don't get a warning with gcc 4.6.3.

Comment: Turning off the warning about implicit conversions "fixed" this :)

Answer (score 2):

You mention two/three problem, it is not clear what of those is your actual problem.

If you just want to compare to dates of which you know that they have the format you mention, you can do a simple string comparison:

```
const std::string A = "2012-11-11 01-01-59",
                  B = "2011-11-11 01-01-59";

if (A < B) {} // A lies before B
if (A > B) {} // A lies after B
```

This works because both strings have the same length, and the digits are ordered from most significant to least significant.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
char d1[] = "2013-02-01 12:56:09";
char d2[] = "2013-01-02 13:14:27";

char *parts1[6];
char *parts2[6];
char *p1, *p2;

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
     parts1[i] = strtok_r(i?0:d1, "-: ", &p1);
     parts2[i] = strtok_r(i?0:d2, "-: ", &p2);
}

struct tm t1, t2;

t1.year = strtol(parts1[0], 0, NULL);
t1.month = strtol(parts1[1], 0, NULL);
t1.day = strtol(parts1[2], 0, NULL);

t1.hour = strtol(parts1[3], 0, NULL);
t1.hour = strtol(parts1[4], 0, NULL);
t1.hour = strtol(parts1[5], 0, NULL);

t2.year = strtol(parts2[0], 0, NULL);
t2.month = strtol(parts2[1], 0, NULL);
t2.day = strtol(parts2[2], 0, NULL);

t2.hour = strtol(parts2[3], 0, NULL);
t2.hour = strtol(parts2[4], 0, NULL);
t2.hour = strtol(parts2[5], 0, NULL);

time_t tt1, tt2;

tt1 = mktime(&t1);
tt2 = mktime(&t2);

double diff = difftime(tt1, tt2) / 60;  // Seconds -> make it minutes.
```